# Why does the compilation of a Common Lisp macro in my environment produce a different result from the book? Is it possible to achieve the same?

Tags: macros, common-lisp, lisp-macros

I am trying to learn Common Lisp with the book *Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to Symbolic Computation*. In addition, I am using SBCL, Emacs, and Slime.

In chapter 14, the last one, the author covers macros. In one section about compiling it, he mentions:

> Since macro expansion can happen at any time, you should not write
> macros that produce side effects, such as assignments or i/o. But it’s
> fine for the macro to expand into an expression that produces side
> effects.

As a way to illustrate bad macros, he provides the following example:

```lisp
(defmacro bad-announce-macro ()
 (format t "~%Hi mom!"))


(defun say-hi ()
 (bad-announce-macro))

> (compile ’say-hi)
Hi, mom!
SAY-HI

> (say-hi)
NIL
```

As I try to mimic the same in my environment, I have a **different** output:

```lisp
CL-USER> (defmacro bad-announce-macro ()
            (format t "~%Hi mom!"))
BAD-ANNOUNCE-MACRO
CL-USER> (bad-announce-macro)
Hi mom!
NIL
CL-USER> (defun say-hi ()
           (bad-announce-macro))
Hi mom!
SAY-HI
CL-USER> (say-hi)
NIL
CL-USER> (compile (say-hi))
; Evaluation aborted on #<UNDEFINED-FUNCTION NIL {100408C143}>.
CL-USER> (compile 'say-hi)
SAY-HI
NIL
NIL
CL-USER> (compile `say-hi)
SAY-HI
NIL
NIL
```

As you see, when compiling the function, the `Hi mom!` part is missing.

Why does this happen? Is this just because of differences in Lisp implementations?
Is it possible to achieve the same output?

I do not think it is the case, but I will put a printscreen from the book, in case this has to do with copying from a pdf and pasting in Emacs Slime's REPL.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SBCL by default already compiles definitions in the REPL. calling `compile` on an already compiled function then probably does nothing.

The `Hi, mom!` message is already printed when the `defun` form gets executed. See your example above.

Touretzky used for his book a different implementation, which used an interpreter in the REPL. The compiler would then invoked by the user via calling `compile`, `compile-file`, or similar.